# Spring Boot Database config wrong but starting ok

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

i have a problem with springboot, if i put wrong my datasource config (example bad password or user) my service start ok, launch the exception PostgresSQL FATAL .... bad password but not stop service. I try so much options but i can't see the problem.
My dependencies is:  (i tried exclude for jdbc (tomcat) from starter-jpa).
My pom:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.14</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>foo.foo</groupId>
    <artifactId>foo-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>fooSB</name>
    <description>Foo Application Server</description>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <ignoreSnapshots>true</ignoreSnapshots>
        <maven.javadoc.skip>true</maven.javadoc.skip>
        <skipTests>true</skipTests>
        <log4j2.version>2.17.1</log4j2.version>
        <maven-javadoc-plugin-version>3.1.0</maven-javadoc-plugin-version>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.8.1</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
        <postgresql.version>42.4.1</postgresql.version>
        <jdom2.version>2.0.6.1</jdom2.version>
        <glassfish-el.version>3.0.4</glassfish-el.version>
        <tomcat.version>9.0.58</tomcat.version>
        <jackson-bom.version>2.13.2.1</jackson-bom.version>
    </properties>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        </dependency>
            <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.rakugakibox.spring.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>orika-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20190722</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jdom</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdom2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Jasper -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>6.4.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>eclipse</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jdtcore</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
                    <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ar.com.fdvs</groupId>
            <artifactId>DynamicJasper</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
                    <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.ws/jaxws-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.jws/javax.jws-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.jws</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.jws-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
                <showDeprecation>${java.showDeprecation}</showDeprecation>
                <showWarnings>${java.showWarnings}</showWarnings>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-javadoc-plugin-version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <detectJavaApiLink>false</detectJavaApiLink>
                <source>8</source>
                <encoding>${file-encoding}</encoding>
                <docencoding>${file-encoding}</docencoding>
                <overview>${basedir}/src/overview.html</overview>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>javadoc-jar</id>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

```
#######################################################3
Properties:
########################
#------------START DB DATASOURCE PROPERTIES------------#

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/300-foo
spring.datasource.username=foo
spring.datasource.password=foo
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=public
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.datasource.type = com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect


server.port=8088
server.http2.enabled=true
server.compression.enabled=true
server.compression.mime-types=text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/css,text/javascript,application/javascript,application/json,application/xml
server.compression.min-response-size=1B
server.tomcat.max-threads=200
server.tomcat.min-spare-threads=40

server.tomcat.accesslog.enabled=true
server.tomcat.accesslog.directory=/tmp/logs
server.tomcat.accesslog.pattern=%t %A %r %s - response bytes %b -  time (ms) server process %D - time (ms) commit response %F


#------------START HIKARI ------------#
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout=20000
spring.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle=5
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=10
spring.datasource.hikari.idle-timeout=600000 
spring.datasource.hikari.max-lifetime=1200000 
spring.datasource.hikari.auto-commit=true


logging.level.com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig=DEBUG
logging.level.com.zaxxer.hikari=TRACE

spring.datasource.validation-query=SELECT 1
spring.datasource.max-active=10
spring.datasource.max-idle=8
spring.datasource.min-idle=8
spring.datasource.initial-size=5
spring.datasource.test-on-borrow=true
spring.datasource.test-on-return=true
#-------------END HIKARI -------------#

#------------START SPRING DATA REST ------------#
spring.data.rest.detection-strategy=annotated
#-------------END SPRING DATA REST -------------#
#------------START JPA ------------#
spring.jpa.open-in-view=false
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy = org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy =org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyJpaImpl

#-------------END JPA -------------#

#------------START LOGGING ------------#
logging.level.root=info
#logging.level.org.springframework.web: trace
#logging.level.org.apache: trace
#-------------END LOGGING -------------#

#------------START PID FILE ------------#
spring.pid.fail-on-write-error=true
spring.pid.file=FooApplication.pid
#-------------END PID FILE -------------#

#------------START ORIKA MAPPING PROPERTIES------------#
orika.mapNulls: false
#-------------END ORIKA MAPPING PROPERTIES-------------#

#---- DISABLE BANNER ----#
spring.main.banner-mode=off
#---- DISABLE BANNER ----#
```

Error launched when starting app (putting bad password)

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: la autentificaci?n password fall? para el usuario ?foo?
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:646)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:180)
    ################################## the service finally started #######################################
    11:02:13.237 INFO  o.s.o.j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean - Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
    11:02:21.741 INFO  o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer - LiveReload server is running on port 35729
    11:02:21.802 INFO  o.a.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol - Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8082"]
    11:02:21.834 INFO  o.s.b.w.e.tomcat.TomcatWebServer - Tomcat started on port(s): 8082 (http) with context path ''
    11:02:21.850 INFO  n.t.c.view.FooServicesApplication - Started FooServicesApplication in 40.316 seconds (JVM running for 41.48)
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the expected behavior, i create a bean that launched request (findAll) for one litle table. This bean have @PostConstruct and if BBDD return error my app will be stop.

Example:

```
@Component
public class DataBaseCheck {

@Autowired
private FooRepository fooRepository;

@Autowired
private ApplicationContext applicationContext;


private Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DataBaseCheck.class);


@PostConstruct
public void checkCorrectStatusDataBase() {
    try {

            log.info("We go check database connection...");
            //call findAll from a little table - recommended one table with not more 10 elements.
            fooRepository.findAll();
            log.info("Checked correct database access");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Error found trying connect database, please check your configuration.", e);
        int exitCode = SpringApplication.exit(applicationContext, () -> 1);
        System.exit(exitCode);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).